# How to preprocess an image in Android (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I want to show a blurred preview in Android using Camera2 (in Jetpack Compose).

No matter what I try, I can't even pass the image from an `ImageReader` to a `SurfaceView` or `TextureView`. Here's the last thing I tried:

The preview itself is a `SurfaceView`:

```kotlin
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = {context ->
            SurfaceView(context).apply {
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                )
            }.also {
                it.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
                    override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
                        scope.launch {
                            val camera = CameraHandler.openCamera(context);

                            camera.startBlurredPreview(
                                it.holder.surface,
                                context,
                                previewSize,
                            );
                        }
                    }

                    override fun surfaceChanged(
                        holder: SurfaceHolder,
                        format: Int,
                        width: Int,
                        height: Int
                    ) {
                    }

                    override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    )
```

while the logic for the camera is here:

```kotlin
class CameraHandler(
    private val manager: CameraManager,
    private val device: CameraDevice,
    private val handler: Handler,
    private val thread: HandlerThread,
    private val lens: Int = CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK,
) {
    private lateinit var imageReader: ImageReader

    val characteristics: CameraCharacteristics
        get() = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(lens.toString())

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    private suspend fun createCaptureSession(
        outputs: List<Surface>,
    ): CameraCaptureSession = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        // I really don't want to use a deprecated method, but there is
        // absolutely no documentation available for the new method.
        device.createCaptureSession(
            outputs,
            object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                    cont.resume(session)
                }

                override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                    cont.resumeWithException(RuntimeException("Failed to configure session"))
                }
            },
            handler,
        )
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    suspend fun startBlurredPreview(
        surface: Surface,
        context: Context,
        size: Size? = null,
    ) {
        val readerSize = size ?: getScreenSize(context).let {
            Size(
                it.width / 10,
                it.height / 10,
            )
        }

        println("Creating image reader with size $readerSize")

        val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
            readerSize.width,
            readerSize.height,
            ImageFormat.YUV_420_888,
            IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE,
        )

        val rs = RenderScript.create(context)
        val blurScript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs))

        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
            val image = reader.acquireLatestImage() ?: return@setOnImageAvailableListener

            // HERE'S where I struggle. How do I blur the image? How do I send it to the Surface? The code below is the last solution I've tried so far....

            // Show yuv image on screen
            val yBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer
            val uBuffer = image.planes[1].buffer
            val vBuffer = image.planes[2].buffer

            val ySize = yBuffer.remaining()
            val uSize = uBuffer.remaining()
            val vSize = vBuffer.remaining()

            val yData = ByteArray(ySize)
            val uData = ByteArray(uSize)
            val vData = ByteArray(vSize)

            yBuffer.get(yData)
            uBuffer.get(uData)
            vBuffer.get(vData)

            val yuvImage = YuvImage(yData, ImageFormat.YUY2, readerSize.width, readerSize.height, null,)
            val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            yuvImage.compressToJpeg(Rect(0, 0, readerSize.width, readerSize.height), 100, out)
            val imageBytes = out.toByteArray()
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)

            if (bitmap == null) {
                return@setOnImageAvailableListener
            }

            println("Bitmap size: ${bitmap.width}x${bitmap.height}")

            val canvas = surface.lockCanvas(null)!!
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
            surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)

            // Release
            image.close()
        }, handler)


        println("Creating capture session")

        val outputs = listOf(imageReader.surface)
        val session = createCaptureSession(outputs)

        println("Creating capture request")

        val captureRequest = device.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
        captureRequest.addTarget(imageReader.surface)

        println("Setting repeating request")

        session.setRepeatingRequest(
            captureRequest.build(),
            null,
            handler,
        )
    }

    companion object {
        const val IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE = 2

        fun getCameraManager(
            context: Context,
        ): CameraManager = getSystemService(context, CameraManager::class.java)!!

        fun createThread(): HandlerThread = HandlerThread("CameraHandler").apply { start() }
        fun createHandler(thread: HandlerThread): Handler = Handler(thread.looper)

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        suspend fun openCamera(
            manager: CameraManager,
            cameraId: String,
            thread: HandlerThread,
        ): CameraHandler = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
            val handler = createHandler(thread)
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                override fun onOpened(device: CameraDevice) {
                    cont.resume(
                        CameraHandler(
                            manager,
                            device,
                            handler,
                            thread,
                        )
                    )
                }

                override fun onDisconnected(device: CameraDevice) {
                }

                override fun onError(device: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
                }
            }, handler)
        }

        suspend fun openCamera(
            context: Context,
        ): CameraHandler {
            val manager = getCameraManager(context)
            val cameraId = manager.cameraIdList.first()
            val thread = createThread()
            return openCamera(manager, cameraId, thread)
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**:
Changing the format to `ImageType.JPEG` does work, but since I need a realtime preview, this isn't applicable unfortunately.

Sometimes the error `Failed to create image decoder with message ‘unimplemented’` popped up when trying different solutions, but I couldn't fix it.

Here all the solutions I've tried:

- [How to convert android.media.Image to bitmap object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775968/how-to-convert-android-media-image-to-bitmap-object)
- [How to convert YUV_420_888 image to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54017087/how-to-convert-yuv-420-888-image-to-bitmap)
- [Displaying YUV Image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192982/displaying-yuv-image-in-android)
- https://blog.minhazav.dev/how-to-convert-yuv-420-sp-android.media.Image-to-Bitmap-or-jpeg/
- https://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/08/12/blurring-images-on-android/
- [D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60070017/d-skia-failed-to-create-image-decoder-with-message-unimplemented)

Answer (score -1):

It seems you're trying to use Android's `Camera2` API to capture a preview from the camera, then blur it using `RenderScript`, and finally show it on a `SurfaceView`. The core of your problem seems to be the transition between capturing the YUV image, converting it to a bitmap, blurring it, and drawing it on the `Surface`.

I'll provide a simplified solution for the image blurring process within your `setOnImageAvailableListener`:

1. You've already converted the `YuvImage` to a `Bitmap`. Instead of drawing this bitmap directly onto the canvas, you can first blur it using RenderScript.
2. Blur the Bitmap:

```kotlin
fun blurBitmap(context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap, blurRadius: Float = 10f): Bitmap {
    val rs = RenderScript.create(context)
    val input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap)
    val output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.type)
    val script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs)).apply {
        setRadius(blurRadius)
        setInput(input)
        forEach(output)
    }
    output.copyTo(bitmap)
    rs.destroy()
    return bitmap
}
```

3. Use the above function in your `setOnImageAvailableListener`:

```kotlin
val blurredBitmap = blurBitmap(context, bitmap)
```

4. Finally, draw the blurred bitmap onto the canvas:

```kotlin
val canvas = surface.lockCanvas(null)!!
canvas.drawBitmap(blurredBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
```

Remember, the process might be computationally intensive. If the updates from the camera come in too quickly, the system might get bogged down blurring and rendering. Consider adding optimizations, such as:

1. Reducing the resolution of the preview stream.
2. Skipping some frames if the processing of a previous frame is not yet finished.
3. Running the blurring process in the background using Kotlin coroutines or another concurrency mechanism for smoother UI updates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the current bitmap itself is the problem. I can't figure out how to properly convert the image to a bitmap. The current bitmap is just completely green. Another bitmaps were empty, completely black or just like random noise :/